# util.crypto.lib. randomBytes is not a function : aws cognito js throws error on authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_aws_sdk_global__.util.crypto.lib.
randomBytes is not a function
```

when I try to authenticate the user using the following code I wrote:

```
import { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUserAttribute, CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } 
from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: username,
    Password: password
});

let userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_1TXXXXXXbXX',
    ClientId: '4da8hrXXXXXXXXXXXXmj1'
});

let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool
});

// THE ERROR IS THROWN AS SOON AS IT HITS THE BELOW
// STATEMENT
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

What could be the reason for this? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't work after downgrading `npm install --save aws-sdk@2.177.0`, try `npm install` after downgrading. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update (12 Jan 2018):**

The `amazon-cognito-identity-js` devs have locked the `aws-sdk` version in v1.31.0, so you don't have to downgrade `aws-sdk` anymore, just upgrade the package:

```
npm install amazon-cognito-identity-js@1.31.0 --save
```

---

Looks like there's a problem with the `aws-sdk` package. It's the dependency of the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` package that you're using.

You could try to downgrade it by running:

`npm install aws-sdk@2.177.0 --save`

Comment: _"Looks like there's a problem with the aws-sdk package."_ What makes you think like that?

Comment: @SuhailGupta It's a dependency of the package that you're using. That means your application depends on aws-sdk under the hood.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Because it was reported on GitHub. See: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/646

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't mean it has be in root package.json

Comment: @SuhailGupta You either downgrade it or wait until the package devs solve this problem in the next versions (if they are going to fix this at all).

Comment: I downgraded to `aws-sdk@2.177.0` but still the error

Comment: @SuhailGupta You should be fine after downgrading to 2.177.0. I found the commit that actually breaks util.crypto.lib stuff. It was introduced in 2.178.0. See: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/0638060402931f572f9f75d77a12bd6c529b0424. So make sure that you've downgraded correctly and have the 2.177.0 installed.

Comment: Even after downgrading it was not working. Then I did npm install and it works now (of course on 2.177.0)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading is the only option right now. I faced this error for hours, unable to figure out the actual issue. I guess AWS should maintain proper versioning and push only stable versions. :\ 
aws-sdk 2.177.0 works just fine. You can use the angular-2-cognito boilerplate by AWS.